# Why getting throw shapeAssertionError while using multi reducer?

Tags: javascript, redux

I am a beginner at Redux and I am currently learning. I have two reducers in my code. When I am combining them using **combineReducers** it is showing an error.
While using multi reducer I am getting **shapeAssertionError** error.
But If I pass a reducer individually to the **createStore** then it is working absolutely fine.
I don't get why it is happening.

Here is my code:

```
const { createStore, combineReducers } = require('redux');

// constant
const ADD_PRODUCT = 'ADD_PRODUCT';
const GET_PRODUCTS = 'GET_PRODUCTS';
const ADD_CART_PRODUCT = 'ADD_CART_PRODUCT';
const GET_CART_PRODUCTS = 'GET_CART_PRODUCTS';

// state
const productState = {
  products: ['Laptop', 'Phone'],
  productCount: 2,
};

const cartState = {
  cartItems: ['Butter', 'Eggs'],
  cartItemsCount: 2,
};

// action
const addProduct = product => {
  return {
    type: ADD_PRODUCT,
    payload: product,
  };
};

const getProducts = () => {
  return {
    type: GET_PRODUCTS,
  };
};

const addCartProduct = product => {
  return {
    type: ADD_CART_PRODUCT,
    payload: product,
  };
};

const getCartProducts = () => {
  return {
    type: GET_CART_PRODUCTS,
  };
};

// reducer
const productReducer = (state = productState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_PRODUCTS:
      return {
        ...state,
      };
    case ADD_PRODUCT:
      return {
        ...state,
        products: [...state.products, action.payload],
        productCount: state.productCount + 1,
      };
    default:
        state
  }
};

const cartReducer = (state = cartState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_CART_PRODUCTS:
      return {
        ...state,
      };
    case ADD_CART_PRODUCT:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: [...state.cartItems, action.payload],
        cartItemsCount: state.cartItemsCount + 1,
      };
    default:
        state
  }
};

// combine reducers
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  pr: productReducer,
  cr: cartReducer,
});

// store
const store = createStore(rootReducer);
store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log(store.getState());
});

// dispatch
store.dispatch(getProducts());
store.dispatch(addProduct('Smart watch'));
store.dispatch(getCartProducts());
store.dispatch(addCartProduct('Salt'));
```

The error I am getting in the console:

```
D:\codes-and-projects\redux\redux-anisul-islam-sir\node_modules\redux\lib\redux.js:550
      throw shapeAssertionError;
      ^

Error: The slice reducer for key "pr" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined. If you don't want to set a value for 
this reducer, you can use null instead of undefined.
    at D:\codes-and-projects\redux\redux-anisul-islam-sir\node_modules\←[4mredux←[24m\lib\redux.js:481:13
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at assertReducerShape (D:\codes-and-projects\redux\redux-anisul-islam-sir\node_modules\←[4mredux←[24m\lib\redux.js:474:25)
    at combineReducers (D:\codes-and-projects\redux\redux-anisul-islam-sir\node_modules\←[4mredux←[24m\lib\redux.js:539:5)    
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\codes-and-projects\redux\redux-anisul-islam-sir\multipleReducers.js:83:21)
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)←[39m

Node.js v18.2.0
```

Why is this happening? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem. Added **return** on **default** case in **reducers**.

Here is the new corrected code:

```
const { createStore, combineReducers } = require('redux');

// constant
const ADD_PRODUCT = 'ADD_PRODUCT';
const GET_PRODUCTS = 'GET_PRODUCTS';
const ADD_CART_PRODUCT = 'ADD_CART_PRODUCT';
const GET_CART_PRODUCTS = 'GET_CART_PRODUCTS';

// state
const productState = {
  products: ['Laptop', 'Phone'],
  productCount: 2,
};

const cartState = {
  cartItems: ['Butter', 'Eggs'],
  cartItemsCount: 2,
};

// action
const addProduct = product => {
  return {
    type: ADD_PRODUCT,
    payload: product,
  };
};

const getProducts = () => {
  return {
    type: GET_PRODUCTS,
  };
};

const addCartProduct = product => {
  return {
    type: ADD_CART_PRODUCT,
    payload: product,
  };
};

const getCartProducts = () => {
  return {
    type: GET_CART_PRODUCTS,
  };
};

// reducer
const productReducer = (state = productState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_PRODUCTS:
      return {
        ...state,
      };
    case ADD_PRODUCT:
      return {
        ...state,
        products: [...state.products, action.payload],
        productCount: state.productCount + 1,
      };
    default:
      return state; // added return here
  }
};

const cartReducer = (state = cartState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_CART_PRODUCTS:
      return {
        ...state,
      };
    case ADD_CART_PRODUCT:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: [...state.cartItems, action.payload],
        cartItemsCount: state.cartItemsCount + 1,
      };
    default:
      return state; // added return here
  }
};

// combine reducers
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  pr: productReducer,
  cr: cartReducer,
});

// store
const store = createStore(rootReducer);
store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log(store.getState());
});

// dispatch
store.dispatch(getProducts());
store.dispatch(addProduct('Smart watch'));
store.dispatch(getCartProducts());
store.dispatch(addCartProduct('Salt'));
```

Comment: Yep, the issue was the missing `return` in the `default` cases. However, note that you should really be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) to write your Redux logic, as it will _drastically_ simplify all the code you've got there.